# Receiving 'TypeError' when attempting to import and create a db using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I have started work on a project and have decided before I get too deep to get my ORM sorted out (this means going back over and re writing my classes). I believe my code is correct but I am getting a 'TypeError' whenever I try to create the database schema using Python. I load up the Python console whilst in my project directory, and type 'from app import db' which works fine. After the command 'db.create_all()' (which worked using a basic example) I am thrown the error:

> 'File
>   "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py",
>   line 2016, in visit_VARCHAR
>       return self._extend_string(type_, {}, "VARCHAR(%d)" % type_.length) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not type'

I am given no clue as to where in my actual code the cause could be, and am at a total loss.

Any help would be great - a lot of code is commented out and some other code left in for now as I'm in the process of adding my ORM but it was implemented without SQLAlchemy initially. Below is my code for '**init**.py':

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, g, request, session, send_from_directory, send_file
from heychef.config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import bcrypt
import uuid
import json
import ssl
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from heychef.models.Agency import Agency
from heychef.models.User import User
from heychef.models.Shift import Shift
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from heychef.models.Agent import Agent

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.agent = None
    g.agency = None
    if 'agent' in session:
        g.agent = session['agent']
    if 'agency' in session:
        g.agency = session['agency']

##########################################################
#############         Agent Routes        ################
##########################################################

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('agent-views/signup.html'), 200

@app.route("/agent-signup", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def agentSignup():
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        email = request.form['inputEmail']
        firstName = request.form['inputFirstName']
        secondName = request.form['inputSecondName']
        password = request.form['inputPassword']
        rPassword = request.form['inputConfirmPassword']     
        if(password != rPassword):
            flash('Passwords do not match.', 'danger')
            return render_template('agent-views/signup.html')
        else:
            hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            agent = Agent(firstName, secondName, email, hashedPwd)
            agent.addAgent(self)
            flash('Account created, you can log in now.', 'success')
            return render_template('agent-views/signup.html')

@app.route("/agent-login", methods = ['POST','GET'])
def agentLogin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.pop('agent', None)
        email = request.form['inputEmail']
        pwd = request.form['inputPassword']
        connection = mysql.get_db()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        result, msg = Agent.agentLogin(connection, cursor, email, pwd)
        if(result):
            session['agent'] = email
            flash(msg, 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('agentDashboard'))
        else:       
            flash(msg, 'danger')
            return render_template('agent-views/login.html')
    else:
        return render_template('agent-views/login.html')

@app.route("/agent-dashboard", methods = ['GET'])
def agentDashboard():
    if g.agent:
        return render_template('agent-views/dashboard.html'), 200
    else:
        msg = "Please log in"
        flash(msg, 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('agentLogin'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and here is my Agent Class:

```
from heychef.models.User import User
#from heychef.models.data.AgentDb import AgentDb
from heychef import db

class Agent(db.Model):
    agentId = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False, primary_key=False)
    secondName = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False, primary_key=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False, primary_key=False)
    level = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    agencyId = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    addressLine1 = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    addressLine2 = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    addressLine3 = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=True, primary_key=False)
    passwordHash = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=False, nullable=False, primary_key=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Agent(firstName='%s', lastName='%s')>" % (self.firstName, self.lastName)

    def __init__(self, firstName, secondName, email, hashedPwd):
        self.agentId = 1001
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.secondName = secondName
        self.email = email
        self.passwordHash = hashedPwd


    @staticmethod
    def agentEmailExists(cursor, email):
        exists = AgentDb.agentEmailExistsDb(cursor, email)
        return exists

    @staticmethod
    def addAgent(agent):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def agentLogin(connection, cursor, email, pwd):
        failMsg = 'Email or Password does not match.' 
        successMsg = 'Successfully logged in.'
        result = AgentDb.agentLoginDb(connection, cursor, email, pwd)
        if(result):
            msg = successMsg
        else:
            msg = failMsg
        return result, msg

    @staticmethod
    def getWork(cursor):
        work = AgentDb.getWorkDb(cursor)
        return work
```

any help would be ace as I'm really struggling!

Many thanks

Comment: One issue I see (likely unrelated): `self.secondName` in your init vs `self.lastName` in your repr

Comment: Hi I changed it and sadly it  is unrelated :-( but thanks for pointing out!! :-)

Comment: as it happens this was related - I only changed the first instance of lastName previously. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be related to a VARCHAR (String)db column and points out that it has received a Non-Integer value ,so there might be a `db.string()` model field with a Non-Integer or empty parenthesis in the other model Classes in your project.

Comment: that much I worked out, I was just struggling to see where it was referring to but it's solved now, thanks a lot! :-)